# How can I customize google suggestions?

Tags: android, android-layout, search

I want to customize suggstions

[image: suggestion looks like this] which I get throught suggestion provider. I vant to add there one image to the left and one sub title. it should look like this:[image: my goal is to customize them like this]

Is that way to change the layout of them? Thanks for all of the answers.

Comment: Which app is this one ? Do you want to do same for your custom data or with this google data ?

Comment: It is the same application, and the data is merged at the second image the google data is shown at the first 2 place. but I need to add this data with image and subtitle to standard showwing of suggestion.

Comment: The question is how can I add my images to google suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please put any response of google suggestion api that have images.
Not sure whether that google suggestion responce gives images also or not. If google suggestion API gives images in responce then yes you can do it. But if they not then you can not able to put images.

Yes, you can put any static images and static description that is common for all the suggestion list. But not able to set any dynamic images if the google suggestion not provided.

hope you got the point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps, I figured out how to add static images, and I have posted it in the answer below. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

I find it out, it can be done with adding 2 more lines:

```
private static final String[] SEARCH_SUGGEST_COLUMNS = {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,//this
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,//this
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID
    };
```

and you can add the image simply to cursor like this:

```
cursor.addRow(new Object[] { -1, "Plants", "Search Plants", R.drawable.pin_bank,0});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yes, As i have said you can do anything with static data. But if you want spcific google suggested data and if it not giving images in response then you can only set static images.